# Running a real time kernel on Debian

Tags: debian, linux-kernel

As I have Debian 8 running on my laptop, I have got some questions about making my OS a Real-Time one:

1. Does the Debian GNU/Linux distribution have an official Real-Time version? (I found that the OS must be patched to run RT)
2. Can I have two kernels on my system: a normal and a Real-Time one?
3. From the perspective of an everyday programmer, what do RT kernels bring in matters of performance?

I issued the **uname** command to know exactly my kernel version:

```
youssef@debian-pc:~$ uname -a
Linux debian-pc 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u4 (2015-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3):

A real-time kernel won't make your system faster... it's about deterministic performance under load and various conditions.

What's your motivation for looking into this? Are you running any latency-sensitive applications (audio/video) that could benefit from a soft real-time setup?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it has. For the current version (stretch) this worked for me:

   ```
   apt-get install linux-image-rt-amd64
   ```
2. Yes, you can install multiple kernels and select the preferred one on startup (grub lets you do this).
3. I guess none (performance improvements). As ewwhite pointed out, real time kernels are for deterministic performance, not higher performance.

Answer (score 0):

sorry about late reply
there is no realtime image for Jessie.

here is realtime image available on Debian https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=linux-image-rt&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

here is realtime image for Wheezy https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/linux-image-rt-amd64